# Is there a way to change shortcuts in midnight commander?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, midnight-commander

I haven't found anything on the topic in the Internet.

The only line from `.mc/ini` that looks related to the question is `keymap=mc.keymap`, but I have no idea what to do with it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Okiedokie... lets see

```
$ man-section mc | head -n20
mc (1)
--
 Name
 Usage
 Description
 Options
 Overview
 Mouse support
 Keys
 Redefine hotkey bindings
```

8th section... is that possible? Lets look

**man mc** (scroll,scroll,scroll)

```
Redefine hotkey bindings
    Hotkey bindings may be read from external file (keymap-file).  A keymap-
    file is searched on the following algorithm  (to the first one found):

     1) command line option -K <keymap> or --keymap=<keymap>
     2) Environment variable MC_KEYMAP
     3) Parameter keymap in section [Midnight-Commander] of config file.
     4) File ~/.config/mc/mc.keymap
     5) File /etc/mc/mc.keymap
     6) File /usr/share/mc/mc.keymap
```

Bingo!

```
cp /etc/mc/mc.keymap ~/.config/mc/
```

Now edit the key mappings as you like and save  ~/.config/mc/mc.keymap when done

For more info, read the Keys (**man mc**) section and the three sections following that.

---

```
$ cat /home/jaroslav/bin/man-sections 
#!/bin/sh
MANPAGER=cat man $@ | grep -E '^^[[1m[A-Z]{3,}'
```

Comment: Thanks. What's man-section?

Comment: @woky it's a regex pipe for troff output (man page format)

Comment: I've been trying to get those good old shortcuts that my old fingers were used to on Norton Commander, and I put that in my ~/.config/mc/mc.keymap :

    `cat .config/mc/mc.keymap
    [panel]
    SortByName = ctrl-f3
    SortByExt = ctrl-f4
    SortBySize = ctrl-f6
    SortByMTime = ctrl-f5`

But hélas, this does not have any effect.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: @Pierre and everyone having this problem years later:

If you put those key-value pairs into `~/.config/mc/mc.keymap` make sure to add them to the correct ini-section. In Pierres case it was `[panel]`.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu the keymaps are in /etc/mc/mc.keymap

Comment: not sure what the +1 here is for. This answer does not provide a solution.